# Struct functions won't work as expected if there are more than 2 elements

Tags: c++

I have a struct named ImAnimstate, which contains 3 float values.
And i have a map that contains a widget's id and an `ImAnimstate`

```
std::map <int, ImAnimstate> menuAnimations;
```

It works perfectly fine if there is only 1 widget, but if i create more than one the `startAnim` and `startAnimDown` functions does not work properly. The function gets called, but the value `enable` just resets to 1 for example.

Here's how i call the function in the widget's code:

```
auto animHandle = menuAnimations.at(id);
if (enabled)
    animHandle.startAnim(ANIM_ENABLE);
else
    animHandle.startAnimDown(ANIM_ENABLE);
```

```
void Checkbox(std::string name, bool* v) {
        static ImAnimstate state;

        menuAnimations.emplace(ImGui::GetID(name.c_str()), state);
        ImGui::Checkbox(name.c_str(), v);
    }
```

```
struct ImAnimstate
{
    float enable, hover, extra;

    ImAnimstate(float m_enable = 0.f, float m_hover = 0.f, float m_extra = 0.f) {
        enable = m_enable;
        hover = m_hover;
        extra = m_extra;
    }

    float menuAnimFrequency = 0.8f / 1.f;

    void startAnim(int type) {
        switch (type) {
        case ANIM_ENABLE:
            enable += menuAnimFrequency * g_Frametime;
            enable = std::clamp(enable, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
        case ANIM_HOVER:
            hover += menuAnimFrequency * g_Frametime;
            hover = std::clamp(hover, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
        case ANIM_EXTRA:
            extra += menuAnimFrequency * g_Frametime;
            extra = std::clamp(extra, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
        }
    }

    void startAnimDown(int type) {
        switch (type) {
        case ANIM_ENABLE:
            enable -= menuAnimFrequency * g_Frametime;
            enable = std::clamp(enable, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
        case ANIM_HOVER:
            hover -= menuAnimFrequency * g_Frametime;
            hover = std::clamp(hover, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
        case ANIM_EXTRA:

            extra -= menuAnimFrequency * g_Frametime;
            extra = std::clamp(extra, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: OT: `static ImAnimstate state;` is not needed. You can just do `menuAnimations.emplace(ImGui::GetID(name.c_str()), {});`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. Thank you

Comment: I realized that the `enable` variable in both checkboxes get reset to 0 after this line `enable = std::clamp(enable, 0.f, 1.f);` Still don't know what causes this.

Comment: g_Frametime is never 0 or below. I am %100 sure of that

Comment: I've edited the Checkbox function so that i first get the id `auto id = ImGui::GetID(name.c_str());`, then emplace, then get the ImAnimstate `auto entry = menuAnimations.at(id);`, and then call the render function with the `entry` as one of the arguments. But it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
auto animHandle = menuAnimations.at(id);
```

That will create a *copy* of the `ImAnimstate` object. It is essentially equal to:

```
ImAnimstate animHandle = menuAnimations.at(id);
```

You can modify the copy as much as you want, but the original inside the map will never be modified.

To solve the problem you should get a *reference* to the object in the map:

```
auto& animHandle = menuAnimations.at(id);
//  ^
// Notice ampersand here
```